# Javascript Jquery dynamic Form data serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**EDIT:**

I need to do a jquery ajax call to the controller within this, it goes to error but does not show me what the error is. It just shows Internal Server Error.

```
                   $.ajax({
                                url: "<%=editNotificationURL%>",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: queryString
                            }).done(function(json){
                                console.log(json);  
                                //alert("json::"+json);
                                //alert("Success!");
                            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                                //alert("OOPS! An error occured while processing your request. Please try again after sometime.");
                                alert("Post error: " + error);
                            });
```

Error message:

```
urldecoder illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - for input String "=e"
```

**Original Fixed:**

I have  a dynamic form that's created by javascript

```
var editForm = document.createElement("form");
                editForm.setAttribute('id',id + "_Edit_Form");
                editForm.setAttribute('class',"subform");
                editForm.setAttribute('role',"form");
```

...

```
var messageField = document.createElement("div");
                    messageField.setAttribute('class',"field");
                    var messageLabel = document.createElement("label");
                        messageLabel.setAttribute('for',id+"description");
                        messageLabel.innerHTML = "Description:";
                    var messageTextarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                        messageTextarea.setAttribute('id',id+"_message");
                        messageTextarea.innerHTML = description ;                           
                    messageField.appendChild(messageLabel);
                    messageField.appendChild(messageTextarea);
```

....

```
      var buttonsDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    buttonsDiv.setAttribute('class',"qmat-buttons");
                    //Create the Save button
                    var editSave = document.createElement("input");
                        editSave.setAttribute('type',"submit");
                        editSave.setAttribute('id',id+"_save");
                        editSave.setAttribute('class',"qmat-button action-blue-button");
                        editSave.setAttribute('value',"Save");
                        //editSave.innerHTML = "Save";
                        editSave.onclick = function () {
                            //alert("edit"+messageTextarea.value);
                            var formName = editForm.getAttribute('id');
                            var queryString = $('#'+formName).serialize();
                            var a = $('#'+formName).length;
                            alert("query::"+formName+"::"+a+"::"+queryString);
                        };
```

...

```
editDiv.appendChild(editForm);
                //Append the fieldset to the form
                editForm.appendChild(editFormFieldset);
                    //Append the legend to the fieldset
                    editFormFieldset.appendChild(editFormFieldsetLegend);
                    //Appends the Message field
                    editFormFieldset.appendChild(messageField);
                    //Appends the Start Date & Time group
                    editFormFieldset.appendChild(startGroup);
                    //Append the End Date & Time group
                    editFormFieldset.appendChild(endGroup);
                    //Append the status field
                    editFormFieldset.appendChild(statusField);
                //Append the buttons to the form
                editForm.appendChild(buttonsDiv);
        //Returns the Edit form 
        return editDiv;
```

Now I need to get the values in that form to Json. So I'm trying something like this:

```
editSave.onclick = function () {
  var formName = editForm.getAttribute('id');
  var queryString = $('#formName').serialize();
  alert("query::"+queryString);
};
```

But the queryString is empty. Looks like I'm missing something minor. Please help on this. Thanks

Comment: You do create input elements for that form dynamically as well? It's hard to tell because it's not in the code you posted. Please consider improving your question so people can get the full picture of your setup.

Comment: Yes it is dynamic. Sorry about that. Will elaborate my code. Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure that the selector (I guess `'#formName'` is a placeholder here?) really matches your form? Does `$('#formName').length` return 1?

Comment: @denisw Yes it does return 1. But still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly concatenate the strings

```
 var formName = editForm.getAttribute('id');
 var queryString = $('#'+formName).serialize();
```

Also, make sure your form fields have `name` attributes in order for `serialize()` to work correctly

```js
var queryString = $('#299_Edit_Form').serialize();
console.log("query::" + queryString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="299_Edit_Form" class="subform" role="form">
  <fieldset id="299_Edit_Form_Fieldset" class="main-fieldset">
    <legend class="legend">Notification ID: <strong>299</strong>
    </legend>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="299description">Description:</label>
      <textarea name="299_message" id="299_message">test 1</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="299_start_date">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="299_start_date" id="299_start_date" value="6/2/2015" class="date-picker">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="299_start_time">Start Time:</label>
        <select name="299_start_time" id="299_start_time">
          <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
          <option value="12:15 AM">12:15 AM</option>
          <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
          <option value="12:45 AM">12:45 AM</option>
          <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
          <option value="1:15 AM">1:15 AM</option>
          <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
          <option value="1:45 AM">1:45 AM</option>
          <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
          <option value="2:15 AM">2:15 AM</option>
          <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
          <option value="2:45 AM">2:45 AM</option>
          <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
          <option value="3:15 AM">3:15 AM</option>
          <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
          <option value="3:45 AM">3:45 AM</option>
          <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
          <option value="4:15 AM">4:15 AM</option>
          <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
          <option value="4:45 AM">4:45 AM</option>
          <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
          <option value="5:15 AM">5:15 AM</option>
          <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
          <option value="5:45 AM">5:45 AM</option>
          <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
          <option value="6:15 AM">6:15 AM</option>
          <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
          <option value="6:45 AM">6:45 AM</option>
          <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
          <option value="7:15 AM">7:15 AM</option>
          <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
          <option value="7:45 AM">7:45 AM</option>
          <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
          <option value="8:15 AM">8:15 AM</option>
          <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
          <option value="8:45 AM">8:45 AM</option>
          <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
          <option value="9:15 AM">9:15 AM</option>
          <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
          <option value="9:45 AM">9:45 AM</option>
          <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
          <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
          <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
          <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>
          <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
          <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
          <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
          <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>
          <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
          <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
          <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
          <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>
          <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
          <option value="1:15 PM">1:15 PM</option>
          <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
          <option value="1:45 PM">1:45 PM</option>
          <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
          <option value="2:15 PM">2:15 PM</option>
          <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
          <option value="2:45 PM">2:45 PM</option>
          <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
          <option value="3:15 PM">3:15 PM</option>
          <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
          <option value="3:45 PM">3:45 PM</option>
          <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
          <option value="4:15 PM">4:15 PM</option>
          <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
          <option value="4:45 PM">4:45 PM</option>
          <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
          <option value="5:15 PM">5:15 PM</option>
          <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
          <option value="5:45 PM">5:45 PM</option>
          <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
          <option value="6:15 PM">6:15 PM</option>
          <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
          <option value="6:45 PM">6:45 PM</option>
          <option value="7:00 PM" selected="selected">7:00 PM</option>
          <option value="7:15 PM">7:15 PM</option>
          <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
          <option value="7:45 PM">7:45 PM</option>
          <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
          <option value="8:15 PM">8:15 PM</option>
          <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
          <option value="8:45 PM">8:45 PM</option>
          <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
          <option value="9:15 PM">9:15 PM</option>
          <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
          <option value="9:45 PM">9:45 PM</option>
          <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
          <option value="10:15 PM">10:15 PM</option>
          <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
          <option value="10:45 PM">10:45 PM</option>
          <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
          <option value="11:15 PM">11:15 PM</option>
          <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
          <option value="11:45 PM">11:45 PM</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="299_end_date">End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" name="299_end_date" id="299_end_date" value="6/29/2015" class="date-picker">
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="299_end_time">End Time:</label>
        <select name="299_end_time" id="299_end_time">
          <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
          <option value="12:15 AM">12:15 AM</option>
          <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
          <option value="12:45 AM">12:45 AM</option>
          <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
          <option value="1:15 AM">1:15 AM</option>
          <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
          <option value="1:45 AM">1:45 AM</option>
          <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
          <option value="2:15 AM">2:15 AM</option>
          <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
          <option value="2:45 AM">2:45 AM</option>
          <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
          <option value="3:15 AM">3:15 AM</option>
          <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
          <option value="3:45 AM">3:45 AM</option>
          <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
          <option value="4:15 AM">4:15 AM</option>
          <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
          <option value="4:45 AM">4:45 AM</option>
          <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
          <option value="5:15 AM">5:15 AM</option>
          <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
          <option value="5:45 AM">5:45 AM</option>
          <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
          <option value="6:15 AM">6:15 AM</option>
          <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
          <option value="6:45 AM">6:45 AM</option>
          <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
          <option value="7:15 AM">7:15 AM</option>
          <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
          <option value="7:45 AM">7:45 AM</option>
          <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
          <option value="8:15 AM">8:15 AM</option>
          <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
          <option value="8:45 AM">8:45 AM</option>
          <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
          <option value="9:15 AM">9:15 AM</option>
          <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
          <option value="9:45 AM">9:45 AM</option>
          <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
          <option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
          <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
          <option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>
          <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
          <option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
          <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
          <option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>
          <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
          <option value="12:15 PM">12:15 PM</option>
          <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
          <option value="12:45 PM">12:45 PM</option>
          <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
          <option value="1:15 PM">1:15 PM</option>
          <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
          <option value="1:45 PM">1:45 PM</option>
          <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
          <option value="2:15 PM">2:15 PM</option>
          <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
          <option value="2:45 PM">2:45 PM</option>
          <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
          <option value="3:15 PM">3:15 PM</option>
          <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
          <option value="3:45 PM">3:45 PM</option>
          <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
          <option value="4:15 PM">4:15 PM</option>
          <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
          <option value="4:45 PM">4:45 PM</option>
          <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
          <option value="5:15 PM">5:15 PM</option>
          <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
          <option value="5:45 PM">5:45 PM</option>
          <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
          <option value="6:15 PM">6:15 PM</option>
          <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
          <option value="6:45 PM">6:45 PM</option>
          <option value="7:00 PM" selected="selected">7:00 PM</option>
          <option value="7:15 PM">7:15 PM</option>
          <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
          <option value="7:45 PM">7:45 PM</option>
          <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
          <option value="8:15 PM">8:15 PM</option>
          <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
          <option value="8:45 PM">8:45 PM</option>
          <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
          <option value="9:15 PM">9:15 PM</option>
          <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
          <option value="9:45 PM">9:45 PM</option>
          <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
          <option value="10:15 PM">10:15 PM</option>
          <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
          <option value="10:45 PM">10:45 PM</option>
          <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
          <option value="11:15 PM">11:15 PM</option>
          <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
          <option value="11:45 PM">11:45 PM</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="299_status">Status:</label>
      <select name="299_status" id="299_status">
        <option value="true" selected="selected">Active</option>
        <option value="false">Inactive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" id="299_save" class="button action-blue-button" value="Save" on click="save()">
    <input type="reset" id="299_cancel" class="button action-blue-button" value="Cancel">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for your immediate response. But still doesn't work :(

Comment: Not sure how to do that as this is a dynamic form generated from js. Sorry

Comment: @Harish, post more of the javascript code that generates the form or post the generated HTML itself

Comment: I have the generated HTMl, but the js is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/6L5pdx2c/1/

Comment: @Harish, if you dont know how to put the `name` attributes let me know

Comment: Awesome. Adding name attr fixed it. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm having one more issue. I need to do a ajax query within that function to call the controller. But it doesn't look like it does that:$.ajax({
        url: "<%=editNotificationURL%>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: queryString
       }).done(function(json){
        console.log(json); 
        //alert("json::"+json);
        //alert("Success!");
       }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        //alert("OOPS! An error occured while processing your request. Please try again after sometime.");
        alert("Post error: " + error);
       });

Comment: @Harish, I think that qualifies for a new question :)

Comment: No I think the issue is the queryString spits out % when there are spaces. Anyway to remove them?

Comment: @Harish, I really don't know. It seems you are using `asp.net`? I highly suggest you ask a new question

Comment: I will. But does this ring a bell: Error message: urldecoder illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - for input String "=e"

Comment: @Harish right, so it seems to be complaining about the `<%` part

Comment: oh ok got it. So it is not able to convert that and evaluate the URL. Thanks so much.